# Which disk mode is most fast and reliable in vmware server 1.9 (ubuntu 64 bit guest)

Tags: vmware-server

I don't want snapshots and they are deactivated in the guest, which is ubuntu 64 bit.

Which disk mode is the most fast and reliable in vmware server 1.9? (I am using scsi)

I am not sure if it is "dependent" or "independent persistent". Actually I don't understand what dependent in this case means.

(I assume "independent persistent" is not the right choice because it is less safe)

So my priority is safe and fast and I don't want snapshots.

*Edit*: My question was not what I wanted. I want the fastest setting. If snapshots activated (while I never use them) is the fastest, then I want this. So which one is the fastest settign for virtual disks?

Comment: Is there any difference between "dependent" and "independent persistent" at all, if snapshots are disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Independent and dependent refer to snapshots.

Independent disks do not get snapshotted *if* a snapshot is taken while dependent disks do get snapshotted.

If you aren't using snapshots, there's no difference in behavior practically speaking.

Persistent and non-persistent refer to whether or not changes are written to the virtual disk permanently.

If a disk is persistent, changes to the disk are written.  If a disk is non-persistent, changes are lost when the VM is shutdown or restarted.

I don't know that either has a specific impact on performance of the virtual disk.